# Cannot get devise/omniauth to redirect after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to get devise/omniauth to properly redirect a user after registering (and later I will be trying with signing in). I am using the omniauth Google gem and basically I want the user once registered to be sent to a plans page. I have read several things here and on other sites and tried every suggestion I can find but having no luck. My applications controller is as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

  def stored_location_for(resource)
    nil
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    'register#plans' # Or :prefix_to_your_route
  end

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    'register#plans' # Or :prefix_to_your_route
  end
end
```

I am not requiring activation but I have tested with inactive sign up as well as sign up just in case. I am not using a custom registration controller or anything, my routes for devise are as follows:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
```

I also have my plans route registered as such:

```
get 'register/plans'
```

I have tested this with rake routes and it is confirmed as:

```
register_plans GET      /register/plans(.:format)              register#plans
```

I am at a loss of what else to try. I am using rails 4.2.4 and Ruby 2.2.1 running on Ubuntu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
David

Comment: Do you already have a controller for `users/omniauth_callbacks` as you required in routes?

Comment: @Зелёный - Yes I do, that part of omniauth works fine, only I always get sent back to the root when it has finished. Thanks!!

Comment: Please add your `users/omniauth_callbacks` controller.